# How to use API Key or OAuth client ID as Credentials to upload file to Google Could Platform?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I'm learning about access Google Could Platform using Python. I have both API keys and the json file of OAuth client ID. However, the official website [Uploading objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-python) is only shown how to use via service account.

```
from google.cloud import storage

def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # source_file_name = "local/path/to/file"
    # destination_blob_name = "storage-object-name"

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)

    print(
        "File {} uploaded to {}.".format(
            source_file_name, destination_blob_name
        )
    )
```

Because some company's limitation, I cannot acces via service account. I go check the official website [API keys](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys) and [OAuth client ID](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user) but still have no idea how to use them.

May someone give me some help to figure this out? Thank you.

Comment: If your code is running on a "desktop" and the user has web browser access, I wrote an article that shows how the process of using Client ID/Secrets to obtain and Access Token works. https://www.jhanley.com/google-oauth-2-0-testing-with-curl-version-2/ Warning: Do not use this code for end users that are not under your control as you are granting the user access to your project and the Client Secret should be a secret that public users should not know. https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access to Google Cloud API, you need an access token. You have several solutions to generate it without a service account:

- You can use OAuth client ID (generate an access token from the client user account). The user account must be a Google account (gmail, play store, Workspace,...). But user aren't involved every time, and you might not want to grant directly the user email on the resource.
- Use [Cloud Endpoint with ESPv2](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/about-cloud-endpoints) (I [wrote an article on this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/secure-cloud-run-cloud-functions-and-app-engine-with-api-key-73c57bededd1) or with API Gateway (managed version of Cloud Endpoint ESPv2 described in my article, but the principle, and the API spec definition are the same). In this case, you can use an API Key, or a user credentials coming from Firebase Auth or Google Identity Platform (that authorized IdP federation). You can define your own service on Cloud Functions, Cloud Run or App Engine as described in my article, but you can also directly wrap the Google API directly in your API Spec.
- Use [Workload Federated Pool](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation), a brand new product, still in preview and without UI (for now). So, up to now, he is not very easy to use and can be difficult at the beginning. This principle is the following:

  - Your external system (or user) has his own OAuth2 authentication provider and generate an identity token.
  - This token is submitted to the Workload Federated Pool which extract the claim, validate the authorization and answer with a federated token.
  - Finally, request the IAM service account credential API to generated an access token from this credential
  - Then use the access token in your requests.